# Push array into array

Tags: javascript

I want to create 2d array and fill it with elements. In every subarray should be one random digit.

```
    var n = 11; //number of elements in subarray
    var listofnumbers = [];
    var rows = [];
    var cols = [];
    var rand;

    //fill listofnumbers array by numbers
    for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
        listofnumbers[i] = n - i;
    }
    //reverse listofnumbers array
    listofnumbers.reverse();

    //fill array 'cols' with another arrays
    for(k=0; k<=n-1; k++) {

        rand = listofnumbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*listofnumbers.length)]; // random digit from listofnumbers array

        for(j=0; j<=n-1; j++) {
            if(j == rand-1) {
                rows[j] = rand-1;
            } else {
                rows[j] = "*";
            }
        }

        console.log("rowsarr at iteration " + k + ": " + rows);

        cols[k] = rows;

        console.log("colsarr at iteration " + k + ": " + cols);
    }
```

For some reason the output is something like:

```
rowsarr at iteration 0: *,*,*,*,*,*,*,7,*,*,*
colsarr at iteration 0: *,*,*,*,*,*,*,7,*,*,*
rowsarr at iteration 1: *,*,*,*,*,*,*,7,*,*,*
colsarr at iteration 1: *,*,*,*,*,*,*,7,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,7,*,*,*
rowsarr at iteration 2: *,*,*,3,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
colsarr at iteration 2: *,*,*,3,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,3,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,3,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
```

and so on till n iteration.

**Question1:** why array "cols" fills all it's elements by the last generated "rows" array? It should push last generated array "rows" to the end.

**Question2:** how could I get 2d array like cols = [[n,n,n,n,n], [n,n,n,n,n], ...]. Now I have only cols = [n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n] ?

At the moment my code looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qqf3fL5L/10/

Comment: `It should push` - except ... you don't `push` anything anywhere

Comment: What should be the final output ? A 2d array filled with random numbers ?

Comment: use this cols.push(rows); instead of cols[k] = rows;

Comment: Your algorithm makes no sense. You build an array in a particular order, then reverse it. Why not build it in the correct order from the start? You select a value at random, then loop over the array to find the index with the same value and "insert" the value. Why not just fill the array with "*" and insert the number directly at the required index? If you want the columns as arrays, you need to create new arrays and put the values into them.

Comment: @JaromandaX if I'll replace `cols[k] = rows;` with `cols.push(rows);` nothing will change

@Weedoze Not quite so. I want to output 2d array with only one random digit in every subarray. This digit should be generated for all of subarrays.

@JYoThI unfortunately no changes https://jsfiddle.net/qqf3fL5L/2/

@RobG you are right about array invertation and other things but the main question is why array "cols" fills **all** it's elements by the last generated "rows" array? It should push last generated array "rows" to the end.

Comment: @RobG I simplified code and fix two errors like you said: https://jsfiddle.net/qqf3fL5L/6/ . But why all the rows contains same random digit?

Comment: I've simplified the code as much as i could: https://jsfiddle.net/qqf3fL5L/10/ . Why all the rows conteins the same random number?

Comment: please add a wanted result (data structure with data) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

you should declare array 'rows' inside the first loop like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qqf3fL5L/12/

```
for(k=0; k<n; k++) {
        var rows = [];
                for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
                    rows[j] = "*";
                }

                cols[k] = rows;
                var rand = listofnumbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*listofnumbers.length)]; // random digit from listofnumbers array
                cols[k][rand-1] = rand;
            }
```